Using getopt in C to handle colon-separated options like FFmpeg
I'm trying to implement an option handling similar to FFmpeg. Specifically, I want to support two types of palette options:

Direct palette specification: -p "255,0,0 0,255,0"

Config file palette: -p:c blackwhite


Similar to how FFmpeg handles codec options:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4

Currently, my code uses getopt:
static struct option long_options[] = {
    {"palette", required_argument, 0, 'p'},
    // other options...
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    while ((c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "p:h", long_options, &option_index)) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'p': 
                if (optarg[0] == 'c' && optarg[1] == ':') {
                    // This doesn't work as intended - optarg becomes ":c"
                    load_palette_from_config(optarg + 2);
                } else {
                    parse_numeric_palette(optarg);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

The problem is that when using -p:c blackwhite, getopt treats :c as the argument to -p, causing the palette loading to fail.
Is there a way to achieve this FFmpeg-like option handling using getopt?

getopt() doesn't support this. It's very simple, it only supports standard option formats.

You'll likely do best finding and using the option handling code that FFmpeg uses.

getopt is intended to parse simple single character command line options.  If you examine the code for binaries that use more complex options, such as ffmpeg, you will see that they parse the command line without the use of getopt.
You can still use getopt for your case example.  When you use "p:h" then you must expect that "cmd -p:c foobar" will cause ':c' to be returned as optarg.   In that case then YOU must peel the next value off the arglist by examining argv[optind] and if appropriate incrementing optind before the next iteration.  Your 'if' section should look something like ....
    if (optarg[0] == ':' && optarg[1] == 'c') {
        if (!(optind < argc )) panic(BAD_ARGV);
        if (! valid_color(argv[optind])) panic(BAD_ARGV);
        load_palette_from_config(argv[optind]);
        optind++;
    } else { ...


Did you test this?  Because with GNU getopt() mulitple arguments such as ... -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4 are not going to work: "The default is to permute the contents of argv while scanning it so that eventually all the non-options are at the end."  And with a POSIX-compliant getopt(): "POSIX demands the following behavior: the first non-option stops option processing."

@AndrewHenle Yes, it does work for me!

@N00B_141 Try more complex commands with multiple instances of things like -c:a copy -c:v libx264,  GNU getopt() will move copy and libx264 to the end, as non-option arguments.  But see Ian Abbott's comment under my answer.

No, you can't use getopt() like that.
First, a POSIX-compliant getopt() will stop processing at the first non-option:

If, when getopt() is called, any of the following is true:
 argv[optind]  is a null pointer
*argv[optind]  is not the character '-'
 argv[optind]  points to the string "-"

getopt() shall return -1 without changing optind. If:
argv[optind]   points to the string "--"

getopt() shall return -1 after incrementing optind.

or, this can be stated simply, per GNU's getopt() documentation:

POSIX demands the following behavior: the first non-option stops option processing.

Nor can you use GNU's extended features.  N.B. the bolding that I added:

The default is to permute the contents of argv while scanning it so that eventually all the non-options are at the end. This allows options to be given in any order, even with programs that were not written to expect this.

GNU's getopt() reorders your arguments.
So a POSIX-compliant getopt() will process as options the arguments from the input ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4 as

-i input.mp4
-c:v

and that's all.  The remaining libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4 will be treated as non-option arguments.
And GNU's extended getopt() will process the arguments as options from the input ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4 as something like

-i input.mp4
-c:v
-c:a

And then libx264 copy output.mp4 will be processed as non-option argument, likely in that order.
Neither of which is what you seem to require.

Would probably need to experiment with GNU getopts use of - at the beginning of the optstring to get the desired behavior. That should prevent the reordering of the arguments, and each non-option argument will be handled as if it was the argument of an option with character code 1. So the option handling code would need to be written to expect such options and their arguments in the appropriate places.

@IanAbbott That might be possible, given the "If the options argument string begins with a hyphen (‘-’), this is treated specially. It permits arguments that are not options to be returned as if they were associated with option character ‘\1’." wording.  I'll experiment some when I get some time, which unfortunately probably won't be for a few days.  Writing a loop that effectively reprocesses the previous argument with additional information is going to be challenging.
